# open ubuntu 14.04 via VMware

Tags: networking

how to open ubuntu 14.04 with VMware that is suspended because i closed it  without ending process

I closed ubuntu 14.04 without finishing processes now appears suspended and Ubuntu can not open to the page where to enter the password

Answer (score 1):

You could force to have a hard restart of your Ubuntu VM on VMWare. Normally, it's **Virtual Machine -> Restart**.